# MySQL query returning old results

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.6 and mysql.connector to query data from my MySQL db.

I noticed a strange effect: mysql.connector seems to cache results somehow.. If I change the data in the db between to queries, the query still returns the same (outdated) result.

Only when I restart my python script then I get the new data from mysql.connector.

```py
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="...",
    passwd="...",
    database="..."
)

cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True, buffered=True)
cursor.execute('SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `uid`=1')
print(cursor._rows[0])
cursor.close()
```

Returns:

```
(bytearray(b'Old Username'),)
```

Now I use phpmyadmin to change the username of that user:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `name` = 'New Username' WHERE `users`.`uid` = 1;
```

And I repeat the query in the python console:

```py
cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True, buffered=True)
cursor.execute('SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `uid`=1')
print(cursor._rows[0])
cursor.close()
```

Returns:

```
(bytearray(b'Old Username'),)
```

When I restart the python console and query again, I get the new username..

Looks like mysql.connector is not really running that query but instead delivering some cached result... How can I turn that off?

Comment: You should check that autocommit is on in command mode of the mySQL database: `SET @@AUTOCOMMIT = 1;`. That may be off and the transaction doesn't get commited, hence the error.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin: I checked that.. `autocommit` was already on, so it didn't seem to help. `con.autocommit(True)` as proposed in your link doesn't help either, but a manual `con.commit()` after each query does the trick (also proposed in your link, thanks for that).

Comment: Yes I realized that later when I saw that you get the new value after restarting the Python shell. There seems to be a bug either on the Python or mySQL side. I didn't find anything conclusive. Glad it works anyway!